# How do you say “I didn’t know Paris was this beautiful!”

Tags: constructions

**Scenario**

**Person 1**: Look at the video I took in this park in Paris.

*Person 2 watches the video which shows a beautiful sky along with beautiful landscapes and sounds and birds.*

**Person 2**: Wow. I didn’t know Paris was ***this*** beautiful.

This kind of construction is used all the time in English and even though I’m an English native I’m having a hard time describing the function of the word ***this*** lol . However, what I can say for definite is that the sentence *“Wow. I didn’t know Paris was ***this*** beautiful.”* is equivalent to *“Wow. I didn’t know that Paris contained the amount of beauty that’s shown in the video.”*

So firstly, I’m guessing ***this*** is an adjective or adverb. If it is, what kind of adjective or adverb is it?

Secondly **AND WHAT IS MOST IMPORTANT** is what is the French equivalent?

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: You can use *so* instead of *this* in English. So it's an adverb.

Comment: Un article intéressant sur le genre des villes, [ici](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/culture-generale/genre-noms-villes-masculin-feminin/)

Answer (score 1):

> Waouh ! Je ne savais pas que Paris était si beau (que ça) !

> Waouh ! Je ne savais pas que Paris était une aussi belle ville (que ça) !

Answer (score 1):

> *Wow. Je ne pensais pas que Paris était si [magnifique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/magnifique)* !
> [*magnifique* (*très beau/belle*) works with both masculine and feminine nouns, Paris is generally [masculine]](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1608)

Answer (score 0):

On pourrait dire également :

> Je ne savais pas que Paris était magnifique à ce point

Answer (score 0):

Here ***this*** is used as an adverb modifying the adjective "beautiful" and "this beautiful" means "***as beautiful as that***". The [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/this#:%7E:text=DEFINITIONS9,since%20I%20felt%20this%20good.) dictionary says that "this" can be

> as an adverb (before an adjective, adverb, or ‘much’):
>
> - e.g. It’s a long time since I felt ***this*** *good*.

To add another French translation to the ones already given in the other answers, I would also say:

> Je ne savais pas que Paris était ***tellement*** beau (or ***pareillement*** beau).

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/tellement/76263) gives it as a translation of ***so/that*** much (which is the same with *this much*):

> Je n'ai pas tellement mal  =  it doesn't hurt ***that*** (*this*) OU ***so*** much.

Another option would be:

> Je ne savais pas que Paris était ***d'une beauté pareille***.

where ***pareil*** is used:

> [Pour marquer l'intensité, avec une valeur emphatique, laudative]
>
> - Dès sept heures du matin, elle m'apportait elle-même une tasse de chocolat. Je n'en ai jamais bu de ***pareil***. Un chocolat à s'en faire mourir (Maupass.,Contes et nouv., t.1, Morin, 1882, p.853). ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pareil))

You can see how ***pareil*** (and ***tellement*** can do that also) replaces a quality previously expressed in the context, in the same way that "this" refers to "a beautiful sky along with beautiful landscapes and sounds and birds" in your context.

P.S. I like poetic language, so if I was the author of that statement, I would write:

> Je ne savais pas que Paris cachait de pareilles beautés/ une pareille beauté!